# How to write Nokogiri xml output to rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I want to write a db/seeds.rb file which uses an xml file for the source data.

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Collies xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://api.syntra-limburg.be">
  <Colli>
    <colliid>7b524488-c847-4271-a5ee-ca53c0aeb0cd</colliid>
    <collinaam>Summer School: Taalbad Professioneel Nederlands</collinaam>
    <aantalsessies>0</aantalsessies>
    <aantaluren />
  </Colli>
  <Colli>
    <colliid>89ecb4b5-3393-4109-9ea2-b1b1f3126128</colliid>
    <collinaam>Summer School: BA4- BA5 gewaarschuwd en vakbekwaam persoon</collinaam>
    <aantalsessies>0</aantalsessies>
    <aantaluren />
  </Colli>
</Collies>
```

My code seeds.rb file looks like this:

```
...
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

Colli.delete_all

doc.css("Colli").each do |colli|
  Colli.create!(name: colli["colllinaam"], session: colli["aantalsessies"])
end

f.close
```

Within my database alle the name and session fields have "nil" in them.  I tried doing colli.css("collinaam") but that does not seem to work either.

How should I tackle this problem? Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

I had an "L" too much in the collinaam. no need for the bracket stuff just basic nokogiri.

```
doc.css("Colli").each do |item|
  Colli.create!(
                name: item.css("collinaam").text, 
                teaser: item.css("teaser").text)
end
```